# How to change textbox text dynamically in Crystal Reports using a formula

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I just trying to change textbox text dynamically in Crystal Reports using a formula but I did not find where should I put the formula?

Shalini Khare

Answer (score 0):

On crystal report , you can find FormulaFeild section. Right click that and add new formula and apply your logic

**EDIT**

[image: Feild Explorer]

Comment: In Crystal report I did not find formula field for change textbox text dynamically on Right Click. I find display string formula section for user defined control but have not seen for textbox.

Comment: @ShaliniKhare you can see "Field Explorer" on the left side near server explorer once report has been loaded in Visual Studio , From that explorer you will find formula Field section

Comment: @ShaliniKhare , I have edited my answer , please check attached image of Crystal Rpoert , Here you will find 2nd option "Formula Fields" in Field Explorer. Right click on Formula Fields and add new formula , write your logic , save with some name. And just drag that formula to your textbox in crystal report

Comment: Hi Lajja .I got solution yesterday in different way but your solution more easier than my solution.so I applied your solution in my code and get result in easier way and hope It will help for me.                                                                  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Instead of textbox write a formula and place the formula in the textbox place.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1-Insert textbox
Step 2- On crystal report ,Open Formula field section. Right click that and add new formula.
Step 3- Give name of Your formula and click  OK
Step 4- Write down formula to change textbox text dynamically Like
        If{Table.TotalMarks}>400 then "Pass"
        Else "Fail"
Step 5- Save and Close
Step 6- Drag this formula from Formula Field and drop it into textbox
Step 7- Now execute your program

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Insert two Text box (At same place)
Step 2- Write Pass in first textbox and fail to another
Step 3- Right Click On First textbox
Step 4- Select format object
Step 5 Check On Suppress checkbox
Step 6 Open Suppress formula editor and put your formula like

if {Table.TotalMarks}> 400 then
true
else 
false

Step 7 Save and close
Step 8-Apply same for second textbox (change formula)
Step 9 Now execute your program